# What is the difference between Google's plus.people.get and the plusDomains.people.get API endpoints?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin, google-plus-domains

I'm not clear as to when one would use the `plusDomains.people` endpoint instead of the `plus.people` endpoint. Is the `plusDomains` endpoint for Google Apps customers? How about Google Apps for Education? The documentation for [`plus.people.get`](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/people/get) seems to be almost the same as [`plusDomains.people.get`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get), and I'm not sure where else to look to figure out when to use each.

Answer (score 0):

> With the Google+ Domains API, Google Apps customers and ISVs can build custom Google+ functionality and services for people who use Google Apps at college, at work, or at home.
>
> [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/)

The Google+ Domains API is for all Google Apps customers (e.g. their email addresses do not end in `@gmail.com`) that have Google+ enabled. The standard Google+ API is for Google accounts that end in `@gmail.com`